# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method _getResource() In Magento2

Tags: magento2.3

we have override the Magento\Reminder\Model\Rule file by using plugin concept.but we have faced an issue like below

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Namespace\Modulename\Plugin\Model\Rule::_getResource() in Namespace\Modulename/Plugin/Model/Rule.php:174
Stack trace:
#0 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121): Namespace\Modulename\Plugin\Model\Rule->beforeSendReminderEmails(Object(Magento\Reminder\Model\Rule\Interceptor))
#1 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Reminder\Model\Rule\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
/Magento/Reminder/Model/Rule/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Reminder\Model\Rule\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendReminderEma...', Array, Array)
#3 /magento234/abandonedemail.php(14): Magento\Reminder\Model\Rule\Interceptor->sendReminderEmails()
Namespace/Modulename/Plugin/Model/Rule.php on line 174
```

Code

```
public function beforeSendReminderEmails(\Magento\Reminder\Model\Rule $rule)
{
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/aboncart.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    echo "test";
    $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();

    $identity = $this->_reminderData->getEmailIdentity();

    $this->_matchCustomers();
    $limit = $this->_reminderData->getOneRunLimit();
    $logger->info($rule->getData('rule_id'));
    print_r("uirtiueur".$rule->getId());
    //echo $this->getRuleId();
    $recipients = $this->_getResource()->getCustomersForNotification($limit, $this->getRuleId());
    echo "<pre>";print_r($recipients);
    foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {
        /* @var $customer \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer */
        $customer = $this->customerFactory->create()->load($recipient['customer_id']);
        if (!$customer || !$customer->getId()) {
            continue;
        }
        $quote= $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->loadByCustomer($customer->getId());
        $cartItems=$quote->getAllItems();
        $logger->info("Customerssss->". $customer->getId(). "cartItems->". $cartItems);
        if ($customer->getStoreId()) {
            $store = $customer->getStore();
        } else {
            $store = $this->storeManager->getWebsite($customer->getWebsiteId())->getDefaultStore();
        }

        $storeData = $this->getStoreData($recipient['rule_id'], $store->getId());
        if (!$storeData) {
            continue;
        }

        /* @var $coupon \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon */
        $coupon = $this->couponFactory->create()->load($recipient['coupon_id']);

        $templateVars = [
            'store' => $store,
            'coupon' => $coupon,
            'customer' => $customer,
            'customer_data' => [
                'name' => $customer->getName(),
            ],
            'promotion_name' => $storeData['label'] ?: $this->getDefaultLabel(),
            'promotion_description' => $storeData['description'] ?: $this->getDefaultDescription(),
        ];
        //echo $storeData['template_id'].$store->getId();
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier(
            $storeData['template_id']
        )->setTemplateOptions(
            ['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $store->getId()]
        )->setTemplateVars(
            $templateVars
        )->setFrom(
            $identity
        )->addTo(
            $customer->getEmail()
        )->getTransport();

        try {
            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->_getResource()->addNotificationLog($recipient['rule_id'], $customer->getId());
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException $e) {
            $this->_getResource()->updateFailedEmailsCounter($recipient['rule_id'], $customer->getId());
        }
    }

    $this->inlineTranslation->resume();

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: @Marius i have updated with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$this->_getResource()` use `$rule->getResource()`.

When calling `$this->_getResource()` it does not work in your case because your class does not contain the method `_getResource` and does not extend a class that contains this method.

Comment: some places its shows an error 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method \Plugin\Model\Rule::getRuleId() in
NameSpace/Modulename/Plugin/Model/Rule.php:246.Code look like this
if ($this->getRuleId()) {
            $rules->addRuleFilter($rule->getRuleId());
        }

Comment: can u please help on this?

Comment: It's the same thing as above... you are trying to call functions that don't exist on `$this`. You have to pay attention to what object is what in your code.

Comment: $recipients = $rule->getResource()->getCustomersForNotification($limit, $rule->getRuleId());
in this line recipients array is empty and $rule->getRuleId() is not getting.
how can we get that recipients value